# check if string does not contain values

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, indexof

I am using indexOf to see if an email contains anything other than a particular text.

For example, I want to check if an email DOES NOT include "usa" after the @ symbol, and display an error message.

I was first splitting the text and removing everything before the @ symbol:

```
var validateemailaddress = regcriteria.email.split('@').pop();
```

Then, I check if the text doesn't include "usa":

```
if(validateemailaddress.indexOf('usa')){
    $('#emailError').show();
}
```

Something with the above check doesn't seem right.  It works - I can enter an email, and if it does not include 'usa', then the error message will show.

Regardless, when I add an additional check, like if the email does not include "can", then the error message shows no matter what.

As follows:

```
if(validateemailaddress.indexOf('usa') || validateemailaddress.indexOf('can')){
    $('#emailError').show();
}
```

As stated, using the above, the error message will show regardless if the email includes the text or not.

All I want to do is check if the email includes 'usa' or 'can', and if it doesn't, then show the error message.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Use [`includes`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of [`indexOf`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: But how would I check if the email does not include the text?

Comment: Just to explain what Sebastian said, when using indexOf, you always get a number, where -1 means it wasnt found, it will still go into your if, using includes will return true or false and thus will not enter the if, you can also do for example: validateemailaddress.indexOf('usa') > -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple JavaScript function to check if an email address contains 'usa' or 'can'.

```js
function emailValid(email, words) {
    // Get the position of @ [indexOfAt = 3]
    let indexOfAt = email.indexOf('@');

    // Get the string after @ [strAfterAt = domain.usa]
    let strAfterAt = email.substring(indexOfAt + 1);

    for (let index in words) {
        // Check if the string contains one of the words from words array
        if (strAfterAt.includes(words[index])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // If the email does not contain any word of the words array
    // it is an invalid email
    return false;
}

let words = ['usa', 'can'];

if (!emailValid('abc@domain.usa', words)) {
    console.log("Invalid Email!");
    // Here you can show the error message
} else {
    console.log("Valid Email!");
}
```

Comment: This is what worked for me.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that, using includes:

```js
const validateEmailAdress = (email) => {
  const splittedEmail = email.split('@').pop();
  
  return (splittedEmail.includes('usa') || splittedEmail.includes('can'))
}

console.log("Includes usa: ", validateEmailAdress("something@gmail.usa"))
console.log("Includes can: ", validateEmailAdress("something@gmail.can"))
console.log("Does not includes: ", validateEmailAdress("something@gmail.com"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to check, if a string contains/does not contain a substring.

String.prototype.includes

```js
'String'.includes(searchString); // returns true/false
```

String.prototype.indexOf

```js
// returns values from -1 to last postion of string.
'String'.indexOf(searchString); 

// In combination with ~ this can work similar to includes()
// for strings up to 2^31-1 byte length

// returns 0 if string is not found and -pos if found.

~'String'.indexOf(searchString);
```

With the help of Regular Expressions:

```js
// substring must be escaped to return valid results
new RegExp(escapedSearchString).test('String'); // returns true/false if the search string is found

'String'.match(escapedSearchString); // returns null or an array if found
```

So overall you can use allmost all methods like:

```js
if ('String'.function(searchString)) {
  // 'String' includes search String
} else {
  // 'String' does not include search String
}
```

Or in case of indexOf:

```js
if ('String'.indexOf(searchString) > -1) {
  // 'String' includes search String
} else {
  // 'String' does not include search String
}
// OR
if (~'String'.indexOf(searchString)) {
  // 'String' includes search String
} else {
  // 'String' does not include search String
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this regular expression match is what you're looking for

System.out.println(myString.matches("(.*)@(.*)usa(.*)"));

Comment: This isn’t JavaScript.